# How does Facebook sync between the app cache and services cache?

Tags: caching, real-time

on a real time applications, how to cache/sync the cache on the application components layer (i.e android app and the service which fetches data), let's assume that i'm caching the user likes on the application and then the counter for likes increased . what is the best approach to sync the cache or to be more precise the tiny details for it .